# select with condition oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a VARCHAR which value aaa or bbb let say 
depend on this I have to make

```
  SELECT x FROM y WHERE y AND som = 1
```

or

```
  SELECT x FROM y WHERE y AND som = 2
```

I there any way to make this like

```
SELECT i AS j,
case xxx
      when z then som1
      else som2
  end as ABC  
FROM ...
```

//EDIT

I want make something like this (lets say its pseudocode ;) )

```
variable VARCHAR;

SELECT id FROM table WHERE age =
CASE variable
WHEN 'aaa' THEN 21
ELSE 'bbb' THEN 99
END
```

Comment: Yes, you can, the `CASE` works exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Ok, and what if I want to make case like this after WHERE

Comment: It would be better if you posted the actual table you have and the names of the columns. It's hard to understand now, what is a table, what is a column and what (if there exists one) is a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT id
  FROM table
 WHERE age = (CASE WHEN variable = 'aaa' 
                   THEN 21
                   WHEN variable = 'bbb'
                   THEN 99
                   ELSE null
                END)
```

However, it may be more efficient and easier to read to just do an `OR`

```
SELECT id
  FROM table
 WHERE (variable = 'aaa' AND age = 21)
    OR (variable = 'bbb' AND age = 99)
```